# node information and messages

Tags: views, nodes, users

I created a user login page, and used the [login destination module](https://www.drupal.org/project/login_destination) to redirect my user to a new "front page" I created using views.

On this "front page" I call all the nodes created by the logged in user, so a user can see newly created nodes.

My question is, how do I call a message or view which tells my user when a node has been deleted or edited?  This "front page" acts as a 'notification wall', which the user can see everything that is added or edited.  It will become more complex later where admins will be able to edit user nodes.  So I need to let the user know when he/admin has edited or deleted a node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For long term logging of activities on a website to show on a wall look at [Message](https://www.drupal.org/project/message) module. It helps to support the idea of an *Activity Stream* on a site.

> The Message module is the core of the message stack. It enables
>   logging and displaying system events in a number of different use
>   cases. Events that are recorded over time are sometimes call activity
>   streams. Exportable messages subtypes can be created for different use
>   cases with custom fields and display (view) modes.

Comment: Perfect! exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can used [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules), and/or [Views Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_rules).

Here is the rule that you need to created:

1. **Event:** When a node from a content have been delete or updated.
2. **Condition:** based on role.
3. **Action:** message display if a node from an specific content type have been remove or updated

Comment: It sounds like if an Admin or he edits a node he wants that information to show, regardless of if the edit occurred while he was asleep, or logged out, your solution only deals with immediate status notifications. For long term recording of such events look at https://www.drupal.org/project/message

Comment: Thanks, this works. But I can only display the message as a status, warning or error. That appears only once.  I want the message to display on the 'front page' and stay there. Similarly to when a new node is created, and shown on the front page of your site.

Comment: Thanks @tenken. I will try your solution. Will let you know.